# .htaccess if url not ends with extension, add slash at the end

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I just started learning regular expressions and I just can't figure this out. I need to force a slash at the end of an URL if it not contains an extensions.

So to be more clear:

```
example.com/test/ stays the same.
example.com/test.php stays the same.
example.com/test becomes example.com/test/     (See the last slash at the end)
```

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange enough I just found a solution by accident:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

At first it added a slash at the end of every row, even which ended with .php but now it works, strangely enough.

Answer (score 1):

Put this on your .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/test$  /test/ [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But strange enough I just found a solution by accident:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

At first it added a slash at the end of every row, even which ended with .php but now it works, strangely enough.

Comment: So post your solution as an answer and accept it, it will help others :)

Comment: Ok I will. But I've to wait for 7 hours -_- : "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: You have now 13 reputation :)