# How to add slash at the end of url in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect, trailing-slash

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]`

When I'm using this to adding slash at the end it is redirecting like example.com//

But I want to redirect my url

```
 www.example.com
```

to

```
 www.example.com/
```

Can any one suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried searching the forum?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Source: [.htaccess Rewrite to Force Trailing Slash at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780859/htaccess-rewrite-to-force-trailing-slash-at-the-end)

More questions:

[Htaccess: add/remove trailing slash from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417263/htaccess-add-remove-trailing-slash-from-url)

[Add Trailing Slash .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829714/add-trailing-slash-htaccess)

[.htaccess if url not ends with extension, add slash at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714075/htaccess-if-url-not-ends-with-extension-add-slash-at-the-end)

Comment: `RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{index.php} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^[^/]*$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]` when im using this I'm getting two slashes at the end of url, but i just need only one slash, can u suggest me?